# TimeSeriesSplit with GridSearchCV fails for n_splits>2

Tags: scikit-learn, time-series, grid-search

I am trying to combine a TimeSeriesSplit with GridSearchCV, using scikit-learn 0.18.1.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('MMS', MinMaxScaler()),
        ('VT', VarianceThreshold(threshold=0.005)),
        ('SKB',SelectKBest(chi2, k=90)),
        ('rf', RandomForestClassifier(class_weight='balanced', random_state=1))])

tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=n)
gridsearch = GridSearchCV(pipeline, dict, cv=tscv, n_jobs=1, scoring="roc_auc")
gridsearch.fit(X,y)
```

The shape of X and y are

```
X.shape == (99942, 2867)
y.shape == (99918,)
```

For `n=2`, this works perfectly fine. However, when `n=3`, I get the following error:

```
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

The relevant part of the stack trace is this piece of code from `sklearn/metrics/scorer.py`:

```
y_type = type_of_target(y)
y_pred = clf.predict_proba(X)
if y_type == "binary":
    y_pred = y_pred[:, 1]
```

What is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: what is the shape of `X` and `y`?

Comment: Also show the code whats in pipeline

Comment: Thanks for your remarks, I've updated the question.

Comment: Why does your X and y have different lengths?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have only one class present in one of your test splits.

This will show you how many samples from each class are in your splits:

```
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(3)
for i, (train, test) in enumerate(tscv.split(X, y)):
    print("Class occurrences in train split #%d: %s" % 
           (i, np.unique(y[train], return_counts=True)))
    print("Class occurrences in test split #%d: %s" % 
           (i, np.unique(y[test], return_counts=True)))
```